# What are the alternatives to Domain Driven Design under MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I understand the value in DDD approach, but sometimes it seems to be overkill and creates confusion.  What other ways can I approach a web application design in Asp.net MVC ?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What specifically is overkill about DDD?

You could try Test Driven Development, and focus on building your test cases to assist in building only the business logic necessary to pass your tests. I'm not a huge fan, but it's an option.

As for DDD, I tend to view it as a general idea... focusing on understanding my "domain" first... the problems at hand, the objects i'm working with... I build my models first, tools to manipulate them second, and then the business logic on top for solving my domain problems by business requirement. Usually I work on persistence mechanics next, and presentation last.

I guess my point is, there's lots of buzzwords behind the ideologies in systems development... and other than fanatics there aren't black and white borders to them all.

If you let me know what in particular you find cumbersome/overkill, what you're trying to avoid or trying to achieve, I could answer your question better.

Comment: model objects are often property bags, with no behavior for example.

Comment: aye, and in a programming language you may want that... POCOS... but for me, DDD is about figuring out what I want to do with it all... if im building a dietary application, my domain then is not simply "i need Fruit and Vegetable objects", but "what do I need to do with them? what happens when i chop a carrot? or slice an apple?" etc... silly metaphor I know, but I think you get the point... your objects may look like property bags, but in DDD, your behaviors and services (business logic) is the majority of the domain. maybe im nuts or staying stuff you understand already.

Comment: looking at your profile, you have far more rep and badges than I, so forgive me if you already knew this. Try a TDD focus for a bit and let me know what you think. I'm not a fan really.

Comment: no i dont know much, just ask a million questions

Comment: haha... at least they are good questions. I've noticed many on here just want a quick javascript snippet. :) If I could offer another suggestion... check out the Programmers site here on StackOverflow... it is more oriented toward philosophy/ideology/practice behind developing software. I'm sure you could capture some guru attention there and get better answers than my quick quips. thanks for the bump, it's hard to get a rep roll going.

Comment: For my point of view, TDD has completely nothing to do with the area of DDD and therefore can not be considered as an alternative. I mean, TDD is for example just a way how you can realize a DDD oriented application.